# How to download a file from webpage using Htmlunit having javascript in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I am actually trying to click on a link to download a file from :

http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2013

The html code for the line I am trying to download is:

```
<a id="a_file" title="Download the zip data file"      href="javascript:return true;" target="nullDisplay">HISTDATA_COM_MT_EURUSD_M1_2013.zip</a>
```

And the java code is:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
HtmlPage htmlPage=webClient.getPage("http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2016/7");
List<HtmlAnchor> anchors=htmlPage.getAnchors();
HtmlAnchor anchor = null;
for (int i = 0; i < anchors.size(); ++i) {
    anchor = anchors.get(i);
    String sAnchor = anchor.asText();

    if (sAnchor.equals("HISTDATA_COM_MT_EURUSD_M1_201607.zip"))
        break;
}
Page p = anchor.click();

webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
InputStream is = p.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
int b = 0;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)b);
}
```

The error message i get is:

```
Jul 12, 2016 1:29:57 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter error
SEVERE: error: message=[invalid return] sourceName=[javascript url] line=[88] lineSource=[return true;] lineOffset=[7]
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: invalid return (javascript url#88)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:904)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:729)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:694)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:746)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:902)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:114)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:800)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:747)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:694)
    at clickPage.main(clickPage.java:38)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid return (javascript url#88)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:255)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:244)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:237)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.returnOrYield(Parser.java:1632)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1022)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:928)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:492)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2660)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1623)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:172)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1615)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:720)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    ... 12 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid return (javascript url#88)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:255)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:244)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:237)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.returnOrYield(Parser.java:1632)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1022)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:928)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:492)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2660)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1623)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:172)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1615)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:720)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:889)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:729)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:694)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:746)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:902)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:114)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:800)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:747)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:694)
    at clickPage.main(clickPage.java:38)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
return true;
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my code and how to download file from the given link.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Complete solution 
//1. open page 
//2. list the urls of that page using xpath
//3. download all file of that url .

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomAttr;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Crawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        String baseUrl= "Enter base http/https url here";
        String url1 = baseUrl+ "add addational url of main page";
        String xpathofdownlaodlinks = "xpath of file url or--> html/body/div/div[3]/a/@href";

        String pathToSaveFile="d:\\local\\to\\save\\files";

        String fileExt = ".txt";

        WebClient webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        HtmlPage page = webclient.getPage(url1);

        List<DomAttr> links = (List<DomAttr>) page.getByXPath(xpathofdownlaodlinks);

        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors=page.getAnchors();

        for (DomAttr object : links) {
            String link = baseUrl+object.getValue()+""; 
            Date d=new Date();

            downlaodRawFile(link,pathToSaveFile +d.getTime() + fileExt);
        }    
        webclient.close();
    }

    public static void downlaodRawFile(String link,String fileName) throws IOException, Throwable{
              URL               url  = new URL( link );
              HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
              Map< String, List< String >> header = http.getHeaderFields();
              while( isRedirected( header )) {
                 link = header.get( "Location" ).get( 0 );
                 url    = new URL( link );
                 http   = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 header = http.getHeaderFields();
              }
              InputStream  input  = http.getInputStream();
              byte[]       buffer = new byte[4096];
              int          n      = -1;
              OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( new File( fileName ));
              while ((n = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                 output.write( buffer, 0, n );
              }
              output.close();
    }

    private static boolean isRedirected( Map<String, List<String>> header ) {
          for( String hv : header.get( null )) {
             if(   hv.contains( " 301 " )
                || hv.contains( " 302 " )) return true;
          }
          return false;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting, the error is now fixed in [SVN](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/12847/).

Please use [latest build](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) or snapshot.